# VS2015 cl Can't find CRT libs (stdio.h, ctype.h etc.) when building on command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

- I have installed the latest VS2015 Professional version.
- Opened the Visual Studio command prompt and ran vcvars32.bat
- wrote a simple helloworld.cpp program (includes stdio.h and prints "hello world")
- tried **cl helloworld.cpp**

I get the following error:

```
c:\test>cl helloworld.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

helloworld.cpp
helloworld.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
```

The include paths set by the vcvars32.bat are:

```
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\winrt;
```

Note that the paths in the environment variable are "*C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\**wdf**\winrt;*" etc. However, the actual location of the files is *C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\**10.0.10240.0**\winrt;*

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help greatly appreciated.

*p.s. My real purpose is to build the boost 1.58 library (but it suffers from the same issue as above, so first wanted to isolate the problem).*

*p.p.s. I noticed the following environment variables. But I'm unable to change them.*

```
WindowsSDKLibVersion=wdf\
WindowsSDKVersion=wdf\
```

Comment: Do you have stdio.h in one of those directories?

Comment: Yes. The files are all there in the correct places in include\10.0.10240.0, however not in include\wdf

Comment: The vcvars script assumes that only version numbers appear in the include subdirectory.  If something has installed something else there than either it's broken or the script is. If you've done this manually then you should undo it.

Comment: Also noted that **#include "stdio.h"** and **#include<stdio.h>** are different.

Comment: @RossRidge
Thanks for the reply. "wdf" is in include\ folder along with 10.0.240.0. I haven't copied it there. I got there when installed Visual Studio 2015, SDKs, Tools, WDK stuff  etc. (not sure which installer caused it to go there.). 

The problem is in the vcvarsqueryregistry.bat (called by vcvars32.bat). That's where the logic of determining the SDK version is. It lexically sorts the folders under "include" folder and finds "wdf".

As I'm not using WDF (Windows Driver Framework) right now, I've renamed the folder to 00wdf and it works for now. I've raised as bug on MSDN website.

Comment: Yah, it appears to be an incompatible with how WDF installs itself and how vcvars detects the version of the Windows SDK.

Comment: For anyone else that encounters this problem here's the related bug report on Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1656623

Comment: @chrisb Does [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32897691/4326278) help?

Comment: I supose you are including <stdio.h> and not "stdio.h"

Answer (score 16):

If you have WDK (Windows Driver Kit - 10.0.26639) installed you will encounter this issue as the include paths are overwritten by the WDK. To get this to work, you must uninstall the WDK and it should work.

Comment: But I need the wdk... What to do?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I added these paths to the additional include path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\Include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\winrt;$(IncludePath)

and added these paths to the additional lib path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\x86;$(LibraryPath)

Comment: Is it possible to combine 14 VC-includes and 10 SDK?

Comment: fascinatingly crappy way to solve the problem, but it works. Yay microsoft and workarounds for their screwups. Thank you very much, build saver. :-)

Comment: this solves problem for VC-2017 on Windows 10 while having installed WDK 8.1 and 10

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem on VS2017 (15.5.5) when building VC++ projects against Windows SDK 8.1:

> C1083 Cannot open include file: 'assert.h': No such file or directory

Checking `Windows 8.1 SDK and UCRT SDK` in the VS installer solved the problem.
[image: Windows 8.1 SDK and UCRT SDK]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem on VS2022 when building VC++ projects against 
Windows SDK.
You need to open "Visual Studio Installer" and modify the components.
To get this to work, you must uninstall 
Windows Universal CRT SDK 
and it should work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52sgk.jpg)