# Unable to compile and link simple C++ program with Visual Studio 2015 command line tools

Tags: c++, cmd, visual-studio-2015, crt

With Visual Studio 2015 I am no longer able to compile and link a simple C++ program using the command line tools.

Consider main.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { return 0; }
```

In previous releases (for example Visual Studio 2012) I was able to compile and link main.cpp easily:

```
C:\Users\bkircher\src\test>cl main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.61030 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.61030.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
```

And done.

With Visual Studio 2015 however, I no longer have proper CRT include and library paths set:

```
C:\Users\bkircher\src\test>cl main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
main.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such file or directory
```

I understand that Microsoft distributes the C runtime as a new Windows operating system component, the Universal CRT.

As described in [Introducing the Universal CRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx), I should use following MSBuild properties to find the appropriate paths

```
$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath)
$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x64)
```

Despite that, how do I get proper library and include paths for build systems other than devenv or MSBuild?

For the sake of it:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>set include
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\winrt;

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>set lib
LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\wdf\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\wdf\um\x64;
LIBPATH=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\1.0.0.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\1.0.0.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\indows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract\1.0.0.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Including the contents of the environment variables was a good idea. Based on the paths appearing there, it seems that you have the Windows Driver Kit installed and you're encountering this [issue reported on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1610302/universalcrt-detection-breaks-when-windows-driver-kit-is-installed).

According to the description of the issue, the `wdf` directory created by the WDK confuses the batch file that tries to determine the latest SDK versions available. For example, instead of

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\ucrt
```

in the `INCLUDE` variable, you should have something like

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt
```

---

The "carpet-bombing" solution: uninstall the WDK, make sure the `wdf` directories are gone, and things should return to normal.

---

If that's not an option, here's a "surgical" solution: you need to edit

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\vcvarsqueryregistry.bat"
```

(back it up first, of course)

**1.** Look for the following two labels:

```
:GetWindowsSdkDirHelper32
:GetWindowsSdkDirHelper64
```

Under each of them, you'll find the following line:

```
@REM Get windows 10 sdk version number
@if not "%WindowsSdkDir%"=="" @FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "%WindowsSdkDir%include\" /b /ad-h /on') DO @set WindowsSDKVersion=%%i\
```

Change it to:

```
@REM Get windows 10 sdk version number
@if not "%WindowsSdkDir%"=="" @FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "%WindowsSdkDir%include\" /b /ad-h /on') DO (
   @if not "%%i"=="wdf" (
      @set WindowsSDKVersion=%%i\
   )
)
```

**2.** Look for the following two labels:

```
:GetUniversalCRTSdkDirHelper32
:GetUniversalCRTSdkDirHelper64
```

Under each of them, change the following line:

```
@FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "%UniversalCRTSdkDir%include\" /b /ad-h /on') DO @SET UCRTVersion=%%i
```

to:

```
@FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "%UniversalCRTSdkDir%include\" /b /ad-h /on') DO (
   @if not "%%i"=="wdf" (
      @SET UCRTVersion=%%i
   )
)
```

That's it. Let me know if it helped.

Keep in mind that this will skip the `wdf` directories altogether. If the WDK command prompt setup scripts happen to use the same `vcvarsqueryregistry.bat` batch file (I doubt it, but...), then they won't work correctly anymore; a bit more hacking will be needed in this case to select the proper batch file for each build environment.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the provided solutions. Your analysis was correct. I did uninstall the Windows SDK and the Windows Driver Kit and everything works like a charm again

Comment: `Let me know if it helped.` Thanks, it helped w/o uninstalling WDK.

Comment: Note also the workaround posted on the Microsoft site linked in the above answer. Making the wdf folder hidden also solves this issue.

Comment: I have the same situation but my vcvarsqueryregistry.bat has none of the labels mentioned above. Windows 7, VS 2015 Professional, I have uninstalled Windows Driver Kit. Still no luck from command line.

Comment: @Bruce You seem to have a newer version of VS 2015 (one of the updates), where the issue above should be fixed. The `32` and `64` labels have been unified into `GetUniversalCRTSdkDirHelper` (and similarly for the Windows SDK). If I read the updated script correctly, it should skip directories under `include` that don't begin with `10.`, so the `wdf` directory shouldn't affect the result. I would try to look at the resulting `INCLUDE` to figure out where the incorrect paths come from.