# boost - adding path to 'corecrt.h'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have a hello.cpp file and I used a tutorial about boost installation from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html).
I did everything like they said and I have a problem trying to run it.

I get:

```
...found 9 targets...
...updating 3 targets...
compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-14.0\debug\hello.obj
hello.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory

call "C:\Users\Paula\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86.cmd" >nul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin\msvc-14.0\debug\hello.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-14.0\debug\hello.obj...
...skipped <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug>hello.exe for lack of <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug>hello.obj...
...skipped <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug>hello.pdb for lack of <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug>hello.obj...
...failed updating 1 target...
...skipped 2 targets...
```

I have corecrt.h in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt
and in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt

I tried setting includes and libraries like here [Unable to compile and link simple C++ program with Visual Studio 2015 command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885229/unable-to-compile-and-link-simple-c-program-with-visual-studio-2015-command-li) but it doesn't work for me. I tried to find help here: [Introducing the Universal CRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx), but I'm not creating any project in VS, just trying to run one with a Command Prompt and I'm not sure what to do in my case. I'm totally new in this topic and I know my question may be stupid, but I really need it. I spent many hours trying to solve it and I have nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution here: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11487

1) Go to %TEMP% folder

2) Remove all b2_*.cmd files