# Installing boost with Bootstrap / BoostBuild and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, boost

to recall an old topic I remark that the workaround described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136978/unable-to-build-boost-1-60-with-visual-studio-2015-pro) didn't work on my pc (Windows 7, Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition/Update 3). After hiding the specified directories, bootstrap produces the typical error message:

```
c:\boost_1_64_0>bootstrap
Building Boost.Build engine

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.
```

In the bootstrap.log file I found:

```
...
c:\boost_1_64_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(71): fatal error C1034: ctype.h: Kein Suchpfad für Headerdateien vorhanden (no include path set)
compile.c
c:\boost_1_64_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(71): fatal error C1034: ctype.h: Kein Suchpfad für Headerdateien vorhanden (no include path set)
constants.c
debug.c
```

etc.

Has anyone any idea to overcome this problem? Or can I build the boost lib in th UI of Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: I had the same problem as you. I installed windows 10 SDK 10.0.15063.0 and managed to get boost to compile. I use vs2015 x86 or x64 native tools command prompt when building the library.

Comment: You can download boost library with **precompiled** windows binaries - https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.64.0/binaries/ This link you can find in official boost page - http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_64_0.html (See - Windows Binaries)

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Have you resolve this and could you please share?

Comment: I have used Windows prebuilt binaries from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

Answer (score 1):

Meet the same problem as you.
This problem is resovled after I add `c:\windows\system32` to the system environment variable `path`.